# Best way of run more than 1 function at the same time but if one crashes, continue running all the others and be able to fix the function that crashed

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing

I'm creating a script that scrapes data from sites. I have at least 10 sites to scrape. Each site is one .ipynb file (Then I transform them to .py to execute). It could happen that one site changes so the scraping code would need to be changed.

I have the following

```
def ex_scrape_site1():
    %run "scrape\\scrape_site1.py"
    
def ex_scrape_site2():
    %run "scrape\\scrape_site2.py"

def ex_scrape_site3():
    %run "scrape\\scrape_site3.py"
.
.
.

(10 so far)
```

I'm currently using a list with all functions and then I'm doing a `for` loop on the list to generate a thread per each function. Like this:

```
funcs = [ex_scrape_site1, ex_scrape_site2, ex_scrape_site3]
```

Then, I'm executing them doing the following:

```
while True:

        threads = []
        for func in funcs:
            threads.append(Thread(target = func))

        [thread.start() for thread in threads] # start threads

        [thread.join() for thread in threads] # Wait for all to complete
```

So here it's executing all the functions in paralell which is OK. However, if 1 crashes I have to stop everything and fix the error.

Is there a way to:

- When something happens in one of the scraping functions, I want to be able to amend the broken function, but continue running all the others.
- Since I'm using a 'join()' I have to wait until all the scrapes finish, then it'll iterate again. How could I iterate over each function individually, do not wait until all of them finish, then start the process again?

I though of use Airflow, do you think this could make sense to implement?

Comment: This seems quite tortured in many ways. Why are you not simply running each in a separate process instead? Then if it crashes, it doesn't affect the others in any way at all, and you can restart and change each independently.

Comment: I've been thinking about it. Can you explain what do you mean 'in a separate process' ?

Comment: In the simplest possible terms, `for p in scrape/*.py; do python3 "$p" & done` starts one process for each matching file. This comment box is too small to explain the differences between processes and threads, but it should not be hard to find existing expositions. In very brief, threads share the same process and memory, whereas separate processes are independent from each other.

Comment: Perhaps see also the `multiprocessing` Python module, though it quite deliberately emulates how you typically work with threads.